# change a static method for a functional component. I have been making class to functional but I have never done a static method yet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

here is what the static method looks like, I want to change the class component to a functional component but functional components don't support it. I am still learning, any advice will be appreciated

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.security.validToken) {
     setTimeout(() => {
        const product_type = localStorage.getItem("types");
        if (product_type === "imp") {
          nextProps.history.push("/imported");
        } else if (product_type === "branded") {
          nextProps.history.push("/brands");
        } else if (product_type === "imp,branded" || product_type === "branded,imp") {
          nextProps.history.push("/imported-brands");
        } else if (product_type === "local") {
          nextProps.history.push("/local");
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: static is a class concept, I don't think it will be possible when you switch to functional components. Is there any specific reason that you want the function to be static ?

Comment: @Kaneki21  I don't know the purpose, it was written by the previous dev. I have not covered this in my course yet. I am breaking the code and understanding it.

Comment: If you fully transition to functional component, then simply defining the given function should work

Comment: @Kaneki21 is there any specific time when this gets called in a component's lifecycle because I don't see it being called anywhere

Comment: static functions are similar to normal functions except for they can be invoked by className directly and used for utility. Have a read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static .

Coming to your question, you have to check the code where it is being called

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier if you could share the whole component, or at least how/where you plan to manage your functional component's state. As said [on this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66057345/how-handle-derived-state-in-functional-components):

> This has a number of ways that it can be done, but the best way is situational.

Let's see how we could create a `ProductsRouter` functional component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

export const ProductsRouter = ({ security }) => {
  // our page state
  const [productType, setProductType] = React.useState('')
  // history object instance
  const history = useHistory()
  // our routing effect
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if not authenticated, do nothing
    if (!security.validToken) return
    // update our state
    setProductType(localStorage.getItem('types'))
    // timeout function
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (productType === 'imp') {
        history.push('/imported')
      } else if (productType === 'branded') {
        history.push('/brands')
      } else if (productType === 'imp,branded' || productType === 'branded,imp') {
        history.push('/imported-brands')
      } else if (productType === 'local') {
        history.push('/local')
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [])

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify({ history }, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```

We could use a map to keep our code tidy and flexible. If there's no particular reason to have a `1000ms` timeout, we could also call `push` instantly, as long as we have a `validToken`.

```
const typesMap = new Map([
  ['imp', '/imported'],
  ['branded', '/brands'],
  ['imp,branded', '/imported-brands'],
  ['branded,imp', '/imported-brands'],
  ['local', '/local'],
])

export const ProductsRouter = ({ security }) => {
  const history = useHistory()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!security.validToken) return
    history.push(typesMap.get(localStorage.getItem('types')))
    return () => {}
  }, [security.validToken])
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify({ history }, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```

Hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: how do we write refactor it if the condition returns two values as if it's 'imp', make it 'imported' and 'branded'? @Moa

Comment: We can use an array with both values. As in ['imp', ['/branded', '/imported']]. We can't redirect to two endpoints simultaneously, though. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have to send values to a splice method with a few if else conditions as (0,1) (1,1) if it's imported meaning two set of values so I tried ['imp', (0,1), (1,1) but it returns 1 and now I tried it with the array and it gives me an array like so [1, 1] @Moa

Comment: Have you tried this ['imp', [[0,1], [1,1]]]? It's hard to help without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve. Maybe create a new question with more info and paste the link here so I can have a look and try to help you more efficiently?

Comment: I tried all types of brackets and braces. However, you can have a look on what I am trying to achieve (goal: best practices) - the way you have done for if else conditions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618768/trying-to-refactor-and-make-use-of-the-map-object @Moa