# Should useEffect be used to get derived state from props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I read [How to sync props to state using React hooks : setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625831/how-to-sync-props-to-state-using-react-hooks-setstate) that is basically about how to mimic `getDerivedStateFromProps` in a functional component. The accepted answer said to use `useEffect`. But the problem is that this would cause an extra unnecessary render, as some comments pointed out. So I wanted to ask a separate question about specifically whether `useEffect` should be used in this case.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what kind of derived state you want? This just sounds like redundant state

Comment: Does it need to be state or do you just need to memoize something with `useMemo`? Re-renders are meant to be insignificant (most of the time) for function components as long as they are not logically inefficient. This might also be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057592/4364635](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057592/4364635)