# How to know when to use useState? (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { generatInitialCheckboxes } from "./utils/generateCheckboxes";
import Checkbox from "./components/Checkbox";

interface Checkboxes {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

const initialCheckboxes: Checkboxes = generatInitialCheckboxes(3);

export default function App() {
  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState<Checkboxes>(initialCheckboxes);

  const isAllSelected = Object.values(checkboxes).every(
    (check) => check === true
  );

  const changeValue = (key: string, value: boolean) => {
    setCheckboxes((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }));
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    Object.keys(checkboxes).forEach((key) => changeValue(key, !isAllSelected));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        {isAllSelected ? "Unselect All" : "Select All"}
      </button>
      <p />
      {Object.entries(checkboxes).map(([key, value]) => (
        <Checkbox
          key={key}
          checked={value}
          name={key}
          onChange={(ev) => changeValue(key, ev.target.checked)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Why is the `isAllSelected` does not need to be in a `useState` and have a `useEffect` to update it? This scenario makes me confused on when to use `useState` and when to not use it because my initial understanding is whatever that changes and will impact the UI need to be in a `useState`

Comment: Go through this doc https://react.dev/reference/react/useState for more information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How handle derived state in functional components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66057345/how-handle-derived-state-in-functional-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Principles for structuring state](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#principles-for-structuring-state):

> Avoid redundant state. If you can calculate some information from the component’s props or its existing state variables during rendering, you should not put that information into that component’s state.

The `isAllSelected` is derived data that can be calculated from the `checkboxes` state, you don't need to create a state for it.

Every time the component renders, the `isAllSelected` will be calculated again. So if the calculation is heavy, [`useMemo()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) can improve the performance.